# pass property as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, document-body

I am using the following code.I want to pass property bgcolor as argument

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(key,valu)
  {
    document.body.key=valu;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="myFunction('bgColor','red');">

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
document.body[key]=valu;
```

key is string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a property as a string, you must use the square-bracket notation rather than dot notation:

```
function myFunction(key,valu)
{
    document.body[key]=valu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work ever,

try this

```
function change(key , value)
    {
        document.body.setAttribute(key, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this since bgColor and onload attribute is so '90s

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setStyle(key,valu) {
  document.body.style[key] = valu;
}
window.onload=function() {
  setStyle("backgroundColor","red")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```